# dev branch show's as merged even i create new custom branch from master

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket, git-merge

i've merged dev branch into master.

[image]

dev branch show's as merged, but i need dev branch for future merges of bugfix Branches into dev branch.

so my question is, how to remove the **merged** tag on dev branch ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `MERGED`-tag in this context only means that it does not have any changes compared to your default (i.e. master) branch.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do anything : your dev branch is still present in git, you can still act on it.

Answer (score 0):

When you add more commits, push to remote: `merged` tag should be automatically removed.

> but i need dev branch for future merges of bugfix Branches into dev branch.

Just checkout your local `dev` branch. Add any features. Then push to remote.

```
$ git checkout dev   
// do some changes here

$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'message'
$ git push origin HEAD         # update remote 'dev'
```